# MassTransit 2.6.1 Request/Response pattern - Response times out

Tags: castle-windsor, log4net, msmq, masstransit

I'm looking at MassTransit as a ServiceBus implementation to use in a web project.

I am playing with the [Request/Response](http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/overview/request.html) pattern and am seeing a long delay between the consumer receiving the message and responding, and the request publisher handling the response; sometimes, it seems like the response is never going to come through (having left it running for 10 minutes, the response has still not come through). the only times that I have seen the handle delegate get called with the response is after a 30 second timeout period and the timeout exception being thrown; in this situation, the breakpoint set on the handler delegate is hit.

The setup is a standard affair - I have a web app that is publishing requests, a console app that is consuming requests and sending responses, for the web app to handle the responses in the callback.

I'm using Castle Windsor, and the container is initialized in the web project using WebActivator:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(BootStrapper), "PreStart")]
[assembly: WebActivator.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(BootStrapper), "PostStart")]
[assembly: WebActivator.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(BootStrapper), "Stop")]

namespace Web.App_Start
{
    public static class BootStrapper
    {
        internal static IWindsorContainer Container { get; private set; }

        public static void PreStart()
        {
            Container = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.This());
        }

        public static void PostStart()
        {
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            ApiConfig.Configure(Container);
            MvcConfig.Configure(Container);
        }

        public static void Stop()
        {
            if (Container != null)
                Container.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**In the web app project** (an ASP.NET Web API project), the WindsorInstaller for MassTransit looks like

```
public class MassTransitInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IConsumer>());

        var bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(configurator =>
        {
            configurator.UseMsmq();
            configurator.VerifyMsmqConfiguration();            
            configurator.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient();

            configurator.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/web");

            configurator.EnableMessageTracing();
            configurator.Subscribe(x => x.LoadFrom(container));
        });

        container.Register(Component.For<IServiceBus>().Instance(bus));
    }
}
```

**In the console app project**, the WindsorInstaller looks like

```
public class MassTransitInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<BasicRequestCommandHandler>().BasedOn<IConsumer>());

        var bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(configurator =>
        {
            configurator.UseMsmq();
            configurator.VerifyMsmqConfiguration();
            configurator.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient();

            configurator.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/console");

            configurator.Subscribe(x => x.LoadFrom(container));
        });

        container.Register(Component.For<IServiceBus>().Instance(bus));
    }
}
```

I have an `ApiController` with the following GET action method

```
public class ExampleController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IServiceBus _bus;

    public HelloController(IServiceBus bus)
    {
        _bus = bus;
    }

    // GET api/hello?text={some text}
    public Task<IBasicResponseCommand> Get(string text)
    {
        var command = new BasicRequestCommand {Text = text};

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IBasicResponseCommand>();

        _bus.PublishRequest(command, c =>
        {
            c.Handle<IBasicResponseCommand>(r =>
            {
                tcs.SetResult(r);
            });
        });

        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

BasicRequestCommand and BasicResponseCommand look like so

```
public interface IBasicRequestCommand
{
    Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
    string Text { get; set; }
}

public class BasicRequestCommand :
    CorrelatedBy<Guid>, IBasicRequestCommand
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public BasicRequestCommand()
    {
        CorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}

public interface IBasicResponseCommand
{
    Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
    string Text { get; set; }
}

public class BasicResponseCommand :
    CorrelatedBy<Guid>, IBasicResponseCommand
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And the handler responding to the BasicRequestCommand in the  console app:

```
public class BasicRequestCommandHandler : Consumes<IBasicRequestCommand>.Context
{
    public void Consume(IConsumeContext<IBasicRequestCommand> context)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("received message text " + context.Message.Text);

        context.Respond(new BasicResponseCommand { Text = "Hello " + context.Message.Text, CorrelationId = context.Message.CorrelationId });
    }
}
```

I was anticipating with all of this running locally that the request/response would be in the order of a few seconds at most. Am I missing something in configuration?

In addition, I wanted to hook MassTransit up to log4net. I am using Windsor's log4net logging facility and have a log4net section in web.config. This is all working fine for `ILogger` implementations provided by Windsor (and also for NHibernate logging), but it's [not clear from the documentation how to configure MassTransit to use this for logging](http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/overview/logging.html). Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as Andrei Volkov and Chris Patterson [were discussing](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/masstransit-discuss/SynchronizationContext/masstransit-discuss/oC1FOe6KsAU/YUrKZKiscD8J) on MassTransit google group, it seems that this issue stems from [switching](https://github.com/phatboyg/MassTransit/commit/0000e38f775507b10e9fef9bbc3862532ec8cb2c) MassTransit to using `SynchronizationContext`, which for some reason does not work as expected.

For the time being one workaround seems to be transitioning to async MassTransit requests, or going back to v2.1.1 that does not use the offending `SynchronizationContext`.

*(Will posts updates on this issue here for posterity if noone else does that first.)*

Comment: Thanks Dav. Reading through that thread, that's exactly the behaviour I was seeing. I can workaround it for the moment, but good to understand what is happening under the covers.

Comment: It has been confirmed by Chris Patterson that the current (as of v2.6.1) implementation of `SynchronizationContext` need some more TLC. A [change was pushed to github](https://github.com/phatboyg/MassTransit/commit/167cac6e4f2d2935fb9c92d61427a4ad44f13366) last night that makes using the context optional. For the time being it lives on the **develop** branch and has not been rolled out officially, but you should be able to checkout the **master** branch, cherry-pick the change I referred to, build and be good to go.

Comment: Returned to the previous behavior in 2.6.3, no longer using the SynchronizationContext since the calling thread may be blocked waiting for the receiver.

Answer (score 3):

The response timeout issue for Request/Response in ASP.NET is fixed in version 2.6.2.
https://groups.google.com/d/topic/masstransit-discuss/oC1FOe6KsAU/discussion

Answer (score 1):

As you're using the MultiCastSubscriptionClient, you must call `SetNetwork(NETWORK_KEY)` on each machine (using the same value for NETWORK_KEY). Also, all participating machines need to be on the same subnet - see the documentation at http://masstransit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview/subscriptions.html#msmq-multicast

For hooking up log4net, it depends what version you're using, but in the latest versions you include the MassTransit.Log4NetIntegration assembly and then call `cfg.UseLog4Net();` in your service bus configuration.

If you're still stuck, you could ask the MT mailing list at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/masstransit-discuss

Comment: Do you have to call SetNetwork even when both the web and console app are running on the same machine?

Comment: I don't think you would need to, no.

Comment: Thanks. Both apps are running on the same machine so didn't think i needed to set a network key. i'll try the group as I can't see any immediate reasons why it's taking so long or not happening at all.

Comment: Should the controller's Get() method not have 'async' in it's signature..?

Comment: no, an asp.net web api action method can return a `Task<T>`. If I wasn't using a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` and could `await` a response to the published request, then yes, the method signature would need the `async` keyword.