# MassTransit/RabbitMQ - Requests going to error queue inconsistently

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, amqp, masstransit

I have a web API that has been built using ServiceStack, that communicates with a TopShelf srvice back-end via MassTransit, sitting on RabbitMQ. Most of the time, things work fine, however sometimes we start to see issues where a large number of the requests start to go to the error queue.

The API is relatively simple, it only has 2 calls. From what I can tell, and looking at the logs, the main call works fine. The other call, however, is a call used to determine the status of the node, and is causing issues. Both calls have been implemented in the same way, using the Request/Respond method.

Here are the log files from one of the errors:

```
2012-08-25 00:01:28,544 [6] DEBUG MassTransit.Messages - SEND:rabbitmq://testapi:password@localhost:5672/test_API.Models:StatusMessage::test_API.Models.StatusMessage, Models
2012-08-25 00:01:28,575 [38] DEBUG MassTransit.Messages - SKIP:rabbitmq://testapi:password@localhost:5672/testapi_web:08cf3caf-6d81-0d5b-0050-56a800810000
2012-08-25 00:01:28,575 [38] DEBUG MassTransit.Messages - SKIP:rabbitmq://testapi:password@localhost:5672/testapi_web:08cf3caf-6d81-0d5b-0050-56a800810000
2012-08-25 00:01:28,575 [38] DEBUG MassTransit.Messages - SKIP:rabbitmq://testapi:password@localhost:5672/testapi_web:08cf3caf-6d81-0d5b-0050-56a800810000
2012-08-25 00:01:28,575 [38] DEBUG MassTransit.Messages - SKIP:rabbitmq://testapi:password@localhost:5672/testapi_web:08cf3caf-6d81-0d5b-0050-56a800810000
2012-08-25 00:01:28,575 [38] DEBUG MassTransit.Messages - SKIP:rabbitmq://testapi:password@localhost:5672/testapi_web:08cf3caf-6d81-0d5b-0050-56a800810000
2012-08-25 00:01:28,575 [38] DEBUG MassTransit.Messages - SKIP:rabbitmq://testapi:password@localhost:5672/testapi_web:08cf3caf-6d81-0d5b-0050-56a800810000
2012-08-25 00:01:28,575 [38] DEBUG MassTransit.Messages - SKIP:rabbitmq://testapi:password@localhost:5672/testapi_web:08cf3caf-6d81-0d5b-0050-56a800810000
2012-08-25 00:01:28,575 [38] DEBUG MassTransit.Messages - SKIP:rabbitmq://testapi:password@localhost:5672/testapi_web:08cf3caf-6d81-0d5b-0050-56a800810000
2012-08-25 00:01:28,575 [38] DEBUG MassTransit.Messages - SKIP:rabbitmq://testapi:password@localhost:5672/testapi_web:08cf3caf-6d81-0d5b-0050-56a800810000
2012-08-25 00:01:28,575 [38] DEBUG MassTransit.Messages - SKIP:rabbitmq://testapi:password@localhost:5672/testapi_web:08cf3caf-6d81-0d5b-0050-56a800810000
2012-08-25 00:01:28,575 [38] ERROR MassTransit.Transports.Endpoint - Message retry limit exceeded rabbitmq://testapi:password@localhost:5672/testapi_web:08cf3caf-6d81-0d5b-0050-56a800810000
2012-08-25 00:01:28,575 [38] DEBUG MassTransit.Messages - SEND:rabbitmq://testapi:password@localhost:5672/testapi_web_error:08cf3caf-6d81-0d5b-0050-56a800810000:
2012-08-25 00:01:28,575 [38] INFO  MassTransit.Messages - MOVE:rabbitmq://testapi:password@localhost:5672/testapi_web:rabbitmq://testapi:password@localhost:5672/testapi_web_error:08cf3caf-6d81-0d5b-0050-56a800810000:
2012-08-25 00:01:33,888 [29] ERROR ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.ServiceBase`1 - ServiceBase<TRequest>::Service Exception
MassTransit.Exceptions.RequestTimeoutException: The request timed out: 08cf4f95-1a2b-d545-0050-56a800810000
   at MassTransit.RequestResponse.RequestImpl`1.Wait() in d:\BuildAgent-03\work\8d1373c869590c5b\src\MassTransit\RequestResponse\RequestImpl.cs:line 107
   at test.API.StatusService.OnGet(Status request)
   at ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.RestServiceBase`1.Get(TRequest request)
```

I do note that it is complaining about a timeout. We have tried variable lengths, and it doesnt seem to help. Looking at connectivity to the database it doesnt seem to be anything in the consumer that would actually hold it up, so I'm not sure if the timeout is caused due to the multiple failures at sending, or if it is simply an issue of connectivity. Generally, the response happens in less than a second.

The request is made with:

```
this.DataBus.PublishRequest(new StatusMessage(request, RequestType.GET), x =>
{
    x.Handle<StatusResponseMessage>(message =>
    {
        if (message.Exception != null)
        {
            Response.Message = message.Exception.Message;
        }
        Response.Node = message.Response.Node;
        Response.Status = message.Response.Status;
    });
    x.SetTimeout(5.Seconds());
 });
```

and the consumer is:

```
public void Consume(IConsumeContext<StatusMessage> context)
    {
        try 
        {
            // Get status from database (not included)
            context.Respond(new StatusResponseMessage(context.Message.CorrelationId, new StatusResponsePacket(context.Message.Request.Node, status, lastUpdated)));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            context.Respond(new StatusResponseMessage(context.Message.CorrelationId, e));
        }
```

Can anyone see anything blatantly wrong with this? I've checked that the API and Service are reading off different queues (the errors end up in the test_web_error queue), as well as checking that the correlation ID and CorrelatedBy is set on the status request and response packets. As mentioned, this only happens with this call, not with the other call we have. I also have multiple servers running this, and it only seems to happen on one server at once, but not always the same one.

Comment: What version of MassTransit are you using? There were some issues introduced to Request/Repsonse in MassTransit 2.6.1 as noted here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12202119/1831. Current workaround is to build from dev branch or use version 2.1.1

Comment: I'm using version 2.1.1. The application hasn't had any problems for the last week or so, however prior to that all messages would seemingly randomly be pushed into the error queue.

Comment: Any update since the original post?

Comment: Unfortunately I never managed to figure out what the issue was. I manually deleted the queue and exchange and restarted the service that uses RabbitMQ. It's been running now on 2 separate servers since a day or two after the original post with no errors being generated at all. I am waiting for a little bit of free time to investigate the errors further and see if there was something I missed.